# Where to put .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have some settings which I want to use in .htaccess file. The settings are for some functionality at `/admin/tool` folder level .. but I want to include some settings for `/admin` and `/` locations as well.

My question is what is the best location to put this file at??

Thanks

**Update**

Just fyi .. I want to apply settings like

```
max file upload size
maz execution time etc
```

Comment: What lines of code are you trying to run?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Place general rules in:

```
/.htaccess
```

Place /admin/ specific rules in:

```
/admin/.htaccess
```

Place /admin/tool/ specific rules in:

```
/admin/tool/.htaccess
```

Comment: does this mean if I want to change the max upload size for a tool in /admin .. do I need to put it in a .htaccess file in /admin? Probably I'd want to use the same settings for /user/tool as well. so do I have to keep different files? many thanks for reply

Comment: Yes, you can apply a max upload size for the entire site in `/.htaccess` of 2MB and increase it to 8MB in the admin area `/admin/.htaccess` and even further increase it to 32MB in the admin/tool area `/admin/tool/.htaccess`... You get the point. =)

Comment: this is called .. I want to make my cake a little sweet, or more sweeter.. or may be sweetest.. what should i add... and answer is : add sugar :D .. thanks +10

Answer (score 1):

You can put your .htaccess in the top level directory and have it apply settings to specific subfolders.