# How to make links shorter? .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have link like this:

```
<a href="index.php?page=login">LOG</a>
```

And my question is how to make it shorter

I want links like this -> `www.page.com/login` but i dont know how

help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login index.php?page=login [L,QSA]
```

Comment: .htaccess file must be in catalog with index.php?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103528/where-to-put-htaccess-file

Comment: Check this post then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache. I mean I hope you have enabled apache to consider .htaccess files