# how to use .htaccess for speeding the spring website customising browser caching for different type of files

Tags: java, html, spring, .htaccess

How to use .htaccess to speed up the site loading. 
I have never used htaccess files before.
Here, different questions have been asked but nowhere explained once I create .htaccess file where to place it and how does it affect  the site loading.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess files allow a server to control User agent caching used by web browsers to reduce bandwidth usage, server load, and perceived lag. For more [read here](https://www.semrush.com/blog/improve-page-load-times-htaccess-file/)

and to learn more about placement of .htaccess file [read this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103561/3185670)